# What is the purpose of "x = x || 0"?

Tags: javascript

In looking through some code I found online, I found this peculiar line of code (Javascript):

```
function values(b) {
    this.b = b || 0;
}
```

I simply can't figure out what the purpose of the `||0`. If I'm not mistaken, since `||` returns a boolean, this value, `b` will always be whatever the boolean equivalent of the parameter is. If `b` is passed as true (ie `1` or `true`), then `b` should be true; otherwise, using one of the `false` values (ie. `NaN`, `0`), this should be false. I then interpret this as the following:

`b` is `true`:

```
this.b = true || false; // will evaluate to true
```

`b` is `false`:

```
this.b = false || false; // will evaluate to false
```

I just don't see the value gained by adding `||0`. Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: || returns the expression to the right if the left side is falsy, not a boolean, unless a boolean expression happens to be to the right of "||" ... it turns null, undefined, "", false, etc into zero.

Comment: In this case, it's used as a default value. When you call `new values()` without a b parameter, it'll set `b` to 0. Related http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/203469/56971

Comment: If `b` is a falsy value, `this.b` will be set to `0`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`||` in a variable assignment is a common way to specify a default value.  This is because of JavaScript's falsy values.  In JavaScript, `undefined`, `null`, empty string and `0` all evaluate to `false` in a boolean context.

For example:

```
var blah = undefined;
if (blah) {
    console.log('got it!');
}
else {
    console.log('not true!');  // this one outputs
}
```

Using `||` in an assignment is a way of saying "if defined, otherwise use this".

For this code,

```
function values(b) {
    this.b = b || 0;
}
```

we can use a truth table:

```
b          this.b
------------------
5          5
10         10
0          0
undefined  0
null       0
''         0
```

The values really of interest are `undefined` and `null`.  So what we really want is:

```
if (b !== undefined && b !== null) {
    this.b = b;
}
else {
    this.b = 0;
}
```

But `this.b = b || 0` is much shorter to write.

Comment: Also note, this will happen even when `b` is `0` or `false`.

Answer (score 4):

**This is a pretty classic question that gets tossed around relatively frequently.**

The main purpose of utilizing something like `x = x || 0` is to ensure that `x` will have a **false** value Boolean, as you've described, but rather than having `null` or `false`, you are returning `0`.

The reasoning behind using the above rather than say, `x = x || false` is that you will end up returning **0** (much easier to manipulate integer or float based data) rather than the other values.

Everything you've suggested is relatively true. For example:

```
var x = x || false; // False
var y = x || 0;     // 0
var z = x || null;  // Null
alert(x);
alert(y);
alert(z);
```

**If you had a purpose to use a `true` or `false` value, your suggestion would be perfectly adequate.**

Answer (score 2):

`||` returns a boolean **only when both of its operands are booleans**. Otherwise, it returns (from left to right) the first operand that isn't "falsy" or the last one if it can't find any.

In that function, `this.b` is meant to be a number but the `b` argument to the function is optional (so it could be `undefined`). To make `this.b` always a number, they used that. So if you didn't pass `b`, it'd look like:

```
this.b = undefined || 0
```

And `this.b` will be set to zero because `undefined` is always "falsy".

A resource on truthy vs falsy: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

The logic behind logical operators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

Answer (score 1):

These are all equivalent:

`this.b = b || 0;`

`if (b) { this.b=b } else { this.b=0 }`

`this.b = b ? b : 0;`

`this.b = 0; if (b) this.b=b;`

Obviously the first one is less typing.

The reason the first one works is described fairly well on the MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

**In short:**

The `&&` and `||` operators have a special feature whereby the values are evaluated for truthyness but the value is returned rather than just `true` or `false`.

In your case, `expr1 || expr2`, will return `expr1` if it evaluates to true, otherwise `expr2` will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

It is a way to define default value for a parameter.
If `b` is `undefined` then `this.b` becomes `0`.

Comment: (While it will also "accidentally" catch values like `""`, it's commonly used with coalescing `undefined` to a default.)

Answer (score 0):

It gives a default value in the case that a parameter or return was missing (`undefined`).  It's idiomatic and confusing to newcomers, but it is a better idea than just letting things go `undefined`.  In the case of `|| 0`, maybe you'll be doing some math later, and if assigned without that default, you'll start seeing `NaN` everywhere.