# Understanding the use of || in the code

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to Javascript and I was trying to understand the use of **||** in the current code.

So, I was going through this [amazing article on web about reduce](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/reduce-f47a7da511a9) in Javascript where he wrote this example

```
const fruitBasket = ['banana', 'cherry', 'orange', 'apple', 'cherry', 'orange', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'orange', 'fig' ];

const count = fruitBasket.reduce( (tally, fruit) => {
  tally[fruit] = (tally[fruit] || 0) + 1 ;
  return tally;
} , {})

count // { banana: 2, cherry: 3, orange: 3, apple: 2, fig: 1 }
```

**[Question]** Here, I am unable to understand two things

```
tally[fruit] = (tally[fruit] || 0) + 1 ;
```

What is this `||` doing here and why did he used it? *(I know this is an or operator)*

And secondly what does this mean `, {})` at the end of function?

Comment: if `tally[fruit]` is undefined, then fall back to 0. `{}` is the accumulator, the base object your `reduce` function starts with.

Comment: Please someone mention falsey values in their answer, rather than specifically `undefined` or `null`. It works for all falsey values.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273498/what-is-the-purpose-of-x-x-0

Comment: `Array.prototype.reduce` takes two arguments. The first is a function and the second is an initial value that will receive the values from the `reduce` function. The `||` is an or operator. So here it is saying if tally[fruit] does not exist + 1 if it does then add 1 to the current value.

Comment: ++ for using reduce. Now that you know how to use reduce, you can forget about all other array methods

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of the `||` here is called a short-circuit evaluation. This means that if `tally[fruit]` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) it will use its value, otherwise it will use `0` (and then add `1`).

The `{}` is the last parameter for the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function which is the starting value (in this case an emtpy object). Generally speaking, this can be any type, including Strings, Numbers, Arrays and Objects. The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) has a good explanation:

> **initialValueOptional**
>
> Value to use as the first argument to the first call of the `callback`. If no initial value is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling `reduce()` on an empty array without an initial value is an error.

Comment: 6 answers, one and a half worth reading.

Comment: Can you mention that the accumulator can be any type? It doesn't just have to be an array or object.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin good idea

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, Just to confirm, It will add 1 even if the value is true?

Comment: @KuchBhi yes. The short-circuit evaluation is wrapped in parenthesis. Anything outside them will always happen.

Answer (score 3):

1.- `||` means "or". The expression means assign the value of `tally[fruit]`, or if the value is undefined, then assign `0`

2.- `{}` is the initial value (an empty object) of the reduce function.

This initial value can be of any type, a number, an array, an object. With every iteration of reduce, this initial value will be modified (for that reason is also called "accumulator").
In your function, `tally` is the accumulator, the object, and `fruit` is each one of the items of the `fruitBasket` array being iterated.

For more info, check the docs of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 1):

|| stands for OR. so if tally[fruit] returns null, undefined, '', or 0 it will be set to 0 and added 1

Answer (score 1):

Its the logical OR operator in JavaScript.

`(tally[fruit] || 0)` this statement essentially means that if `tally[fruit]` is `null` or `undefined`, then it will be assigned to 0.

Comment: It's not "the default operator"

Comment: `console.log(0||1);` will return 1 rather than 0, it's about [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)